# HashSet of Guid vs Tuple<Guid, Guid> as Dictionary Key: Order of Guid Shouldn't matter

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I need dictionary for which key needs to be two guid order of guid doesn't matter. I have two solutions which are mentioned below, I want to know which one is better and which one should I go if in future I need to add 3rd guid as well as part of key. Performance do matter but if difference is not much then should be fine.

**First Solution**

```
 var guids = guids
     .OrderBy(g => g.ToString("N")) // Ordering so key always come as sorted 
     .ToList();

dict[Tuple.Create(guids[0], guids[1]) = "RandomObj";
```

**Second Solution**

```
public class GuidsModel
    {
        public GuidsModel(Guid guid1, Guid guid2)
        {
            Guid1= guid1;
            Guid2= guid2;
        }

        public Guid Guid1 { get; private set; }

        public Guid Guid2 { get; private set; }
    }

 public class GuidsModelComparer : IEqualityComparer<GuidsModel>
    {
        public static GuidsModelComparer Default = new GuidsModelComparer();

        private static IEqualityComparer<HashSet<Guid>> _hashSetComparer = HashSet<Guid>.CreateSetComparer();

        public bool Equals(GuidsModel x, GuidsModel y)
        {
            return _hashSetComparer.Equals(new HashSet<Guid> { x.Guid1, x.Guid2}, new HashSet<Guid> { y.Guid1, y.Guid2});
        }

        public int GetHashCode(GuidsModel obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return 0;

            return _hashSetComparer.GetHashCode(new HashSet<Guid> { obj.Guid1, obj.Guid2});
        }

// usage
var dict = new Dictionary<GuidsModel, object>(GuidsModelComparer.Default);
dict[new GuidsModel(guids[0], guids[1])] = "RandomObj";
```

Comment: A Dictionary is implemented using a hashtable, i.e it's very very fast when retrieving an object based on a given key. Is that your use case? If so, use a dictionary over a list.

Comment: `HashSet` makes more sense. You have no value, so no point using a dictionary. Make a custom type (or Tuple / ValueTuple) with two Guid properties. Have a constructor to take them both. Add the lesser to the first property the greater to the second property.

Comment: @41686d6564 [Example](https://rextester.com/VAO31773)

Comment: Another option, is to just use a communicative hash on and store that for the key

Comment: @imsmn nope, I am using dictionary but should I use dictionary with Tuple<guid, guid> as key or GuidModel as key. The issue with tuple is Tuple<guid1, guid2> is not equal to Tuple<guid2, guid1> therefore, before adding in dictionary I always have to sort guids.

Comment: @Llama in my case order doesnt matter so these two below keys wont be equal

  Tuple<Guid, Guid> a = Tuple.Create(Guid.Parse("e7a84132-823b-4c47-822f-73a156e941ed"), Guid.Parse("798c3105-2be7-4853-a8e8-c2bf65d216f6"));
            Tuple<Guid, Guid> b = Tuple.Create(Guid.Parse("798c3105-2be7-4853-a8e8-c2bf65d216f6"),Guid.Parse("e7a84132-823b-4c47-822f-73a156e941ed"));
I don't know the order of incoming guids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can heavily depend on the context, but I would say that if you want to access the dictionary in more than one place encapsulating the guid "sorting" logic in one place would make more sense. Also personally I would just implement `Equals` and `GetHashcode` in the model itself instead of creating custom comparer.

```cs
public class GuidsModel
{
    public GuidsModel(Guid guid1, Guid guid2)
    {
        if (guid1.CompareTo(guid2) > 0) // when there will be more than 2 guids can switch to ordering collection i.e. new [] {guid1, guid2, guid3}.OrderBy()...
        {
            Guid1 = guid1;
            Guid2 = guid2;
        }
        else
        {
            Guid1 = guid2;
            Guid2 = guid1;
        }
    }

    public Guid Guid1 { get; private set; }
    public Guid Guid2 { get; private set; }

    private bool Equals(GuidsModel other)
    {
        return Guid1.Equals(other.Guid1) && Guid2.Equals(other.Guid2);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((GuidsModel)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(Guid1, Guid2);
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rvvd6g)

Comment: Thanks @Guru Stron I will try out above solution seems much simple than comparer

Comment: I would slightly change Equal as follows

 public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
         if (!(obj is GuidModel source)) return false;
        return Equals((GuidsModel)obj);
    }

Comment: @MurtazaTahirAli `return obj is GuidsModel model && Equals(model);` can be even shorter =)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood you need a `HashSet<Something>` and this something holds two values of same type and the HashSet should also match, if the order is different.

Getting this *ignore order* is quite complicated. But if you use a factory method to create the instances and this factory method takes care of the ordering, then it gets much simpler:

```
// Some class that holds two Guids, but it respects ordering
public record GuidPair(Guid First, Guid Second);

public static class Create
{
    public static GuidPair GuidPair(Guid first, Guid second)
    {
        // Order guids somehow in factory method to ensure
        // correct equality comparison
        if (first.CompareTo(second) > 0)
            return new GuidPair(second, first);
        else
            return new GuidPair(first, second);
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Some source for Guid values.
        var values = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
            .Select(_ => Guid.NewGuid());

        // Create a HashSet with arbitrary values.
        var hashes = values.Zip(values)
            .Select(pair => Create.GuidPair(pair.First, pair.Second))
            .ToHashSet();

        // Pick some "random" element
        var someEntry = hashes.Skip(17).First();
        // Create explicitly a new item with values swapped (with factory method).
        var toCompare = Create.GuidPair(someEntry.Second, someEntry.First);

        // Check if default HashSet comparer works.
        var isAvailable = hashes.Contains(toCompare);

        // Prints "Found { first = Guid, second = Guid }: true"
        Console.WriteLine($"Found {toCompare}: {isAvailable}");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Oliver you have understood right. Your solution is pretty much similar to what Guru Stron has proposed as well.

Comment: You're right. The strategy is the same. The only real different is, I use the new `record` class and *Guru Stron* uses it's own implementation of `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`.